# If $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n = f$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n = y$, does $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(y_n) = f(y)$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

If $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n = f$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n = y$, does $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(y_n) = f(y)$?

In particular I'm trying to prove that that if $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+\frac{x}{n})^n = e^x$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \lambda_n = \lambda$ where $\lambda_n$ is a sequence of real numbers, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+\frac{\lambda_n}{n})^n = e^\lambda$.

I want to believe this is true in general for any $f_n$ and $\lambda_n$, but I've never seen a proof for this before, and I haven't found this stated as a theorem anywhere.

Note: This is not a homework question, but it is related. The homework solutions are already given to me, and they just conclude this is true without justification, but I don't see why.

The main thing I'm looking for a source of this. Is this a theorem from somewhere that I can use? Should I prove it manually? Again, not relevant to my current homework assignment, but I'd like to know in case this ever comes up again. This solutions seem to imply this is trivial.

Comment: “Uniform convergence” is what you are looking for.

Comment: I didn't realize there were multiple definitions. My textbook define it as $f_n$ converges to $f$ if $f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)$ for all x in the domain of $f$.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true in general. Take, for instance,$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}\sin(nx)&\text{ if }x\in\left[0,\frac\pi n\right]\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Then, for each $x\in\mathbb R$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=0$. However, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac\pi{2n}=0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n\left(\frac\pi{2n}\right)=1$.

On the other hand, it is true in the context of $\left(\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, because it converges uniformly to $e^x$ on any interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: I've looked up uniform convergence again, but I still don't understand why it's applicable here. I mean, it intuitively makes sense to me, but I can't find any proof of this.

Comment: You will find a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1714973/for-each-bounded-subset-in-mathbbc-lim-n-rightarrow-infty1x-nn-e).

Comment: I'm not confused about why it's uniformly convergent, I'm confused as to why that matters. Why does the function being uniformly convergent imply $f_n(\lambda_n) \rightarrow f(\lambda)$?

Comment: Let $[a,b]$ be an interval containing all $\lambda_n$'s. Take $\varepsilon>0$. Since the convergence is uniform, there is a $N\in\mathbb N$ such that$$n\geqslant N\implies(\forall x\in[a,b]):\lvert f(x)-f_n(x)\rvert<\frac\varepsilon2.$$And since $f$ is continuous and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lambda_n=\lambda$, there is a $M\in\mathbb N$ such that$$n\geqslant M\implies\lvert f(\lambda)-f(\lambda_n)\rvert<\frac\varepsilon2.$$But then, if $n\geqslant\max\{N,M\}$,$$\lvert f(\lambda)-f_n(\lambda_n)\rvert\leqslant\lvert f(\lambda)-f(\lambda_n)\rvert+\lvert f(\lambda_n)-f_n(\lambda_n)\rvert<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: @J Okay the proof makes sense. Is there a name for this theorem, or even just this concept of a sequence of functions of a sequence? Again, my homework solutions seem to believe it's trivial, but I don't know what to search for to verify if it's something well known or not.

Comment: If it has a name, I am nor aware of it. It is a standard theorem in the context of uniform convergence.

Answer (score 0):

For the particular case you are considering, the usual trick to obtain the result is the following

$$\left(1+\frac{\lambda_n}{n}\right)^n = \left[\left(1+\frac{\lambda_n}{n}\right)^{\frac n{\lambda_n}}\right]^{\lambda_n}$$

and wlog for $\lambda>0$ by $x=\frac n{\lambda_n}\to \infty$ we can use that

$$\left(1+\frac{\lambda_n}{n}\right)^{\frac n{\lambda_n}}=\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x} \to e$$

Refer also to

- [Composition and Limits at Infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/904662/505767)

Comment: Isn't the first inequality an *equality?* But then you have something like $(x_n)^{\lambda_n}$ where $x_n \to e$ and $\lambda_n \to \lambda$, and it still remains to justify why  $(x_n)^{\lambda_n} \to e^\lambda$.

Comment: @MartinR Opsss yes, I fix the typo!

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f_n(x)=x^n ,x\in [0,1),n\in \mathbb N$ which converges to $f(x)=0$ at non zero $x, f(x)=1$ at $1$ on $[0,1]$. But take the sequence $y_n=1-1/n$ converging to $1$,but $f_n(y_n)=(1-1/n)^n$ which converges to $1/e$.